# Should you undo your vote after an answer was edited?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, voting

Let's say you upvote an answer because it answers the question and helps OP fix a problem. Within a couple of minutes of upvoting, this answer is edited slightly - not enough to change it completely but just enough that you aren't sure anymore if the answer is still a good answer and fixes the problem.

I know that you can undo your vote after a post was edited (I'm also aware that at one point there was a bug that that wouldn't work if the edit happened within the 5 minutes grace period) but should you?

If you undo your vote now, is it possible to vote again later (up or down), e.g. when you've had the time to check if the answer, with the edit, is still correct?

Comment: Are you asking about etiquette, or are you asking whether withdrawn votes can be re-cast?

Comment: @user3840170 Etiquette with a follow-up question if it can be re-cast later, even after the 5 minute grace period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, why not? It's totally your call, and there's no shame in changing the vote.

> is it possible to vote again later (up or down)

Depends, if you only undo your vote there's no time limit for voting again, as it's like you never voted in the first place.

However, if you *reverse* the vote after the edit, you can undo or reverse it again only for five minutes, then you'll have to wait until it's edited. But still, I don't think this should stop one from undoing the vote.

Comment: So basically: Only undo once you're sure that the answer isn't good anymore or even now bad?

Comment: @Neph yeah, and no need to feel bad about it.

Comment: Just noticed your edit, that's good to know, thanks. I guess there's no actual "etiquette" rule about this then.

Comment: @Neph correct, no such rule.